# Razor Pages model binding [BindProperty] required?

Tags: c#, razor

I have the following code in my .cs file:

```
[BindProperty]
public ApimSubscriptionRoot apimSubscriptions { get; set; }
```

...which allows me to access the object's properties in my Razor view as:

```
@Model.apimSubscriptions.someProperty
```

...however defining it as a field also works in terms of me being able to display the properties of the object in my view:

```
public ApimSubscriptionRoot apimSubscriptions;
```

Razor code behind (controller):

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet() 
{
    (some code...)
    apimSubscriptions = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApimSubscriptionRoot>(contents);
    return Page();
}
```

Razor page (view):

```
@page
@model Subscriptions

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Your subscriptions";
    ViewData["ActivePage"] = ManageNavPages.Subscriptions;
}

<h4>@ViewData["Title"]</h4>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        @if (Model.apimSubscriptions.value.Length == 0 || Model.apimSubscriptions == null)
```

Any explanation as to why would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide more detail and example code. Specifically the start of your views, and controllers as well as where you have defined it as a field.

Comment: Updated post. This is a Razor page so there is no 'controller' per se.

Comment: I take the the thing you called controller in your questions is a class called subscriptions ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bit old question, but here goes anyway: `BindPropertyAttribute` allows you to access the values entered in the view in `OnPost` method, ie. the binding in this case stands for binding from view to model. All public property getters and fields in model class are accessible in the view since they are considered just object instances that are used by the Razor code.

`BindPropertyAttribute` is required because a new model object is created when the form is submitted and `OnPost` is called, and the attribute then directs the Razor Page to set the corresponding values from the form to the matching property.

Comment: The form needs to have the method attribute set like `method="post"` for the binding to work.