# How to use two forms in the same page in ASP. NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two buttons in my page where each button is nested inside a form. The first button in the first form is labeled Log Out and is used to end the session and log the current user out. The second button is for allowing the user to add a bio to his profile. Both forms use post method to submit data to the server. Whenever I submit the second form(which is supposed to post bio to database) , the server thinks it's the first form that I have submitted and redirects to the action method to log me out. I have two seperate controllers to handle the two forms separately. The controller that contains the method that logs me out has its implementation details shown below

```
 [Route("api/[controller]", Name = "Session")]
    [ApiController]
    public class SessionController : ControllerBase
    {
        
        public IActionResult LogOut()
        {
            //clear all session entries
            Request.Cookies.Keys.ToList().ForEach(cookie =>
            {
                if(cookie == ".AspNetCore.Session")
                {
                    Response.Cookies.Delete(cookie);        
                }

            });
           
            //redirect user to login page
            return RedirectToPage("/Index");     
        }
    
    }
```

The other controller that posts the bio to the database has its implementation details shown below

```
[Route("api/[controller]",Name= "Bio")] 
public class BioController : ControllerBase{
  private Dbctx _dbctx;
  public IActionResult PostBio([FromForm] string bio) {
     var email = HttpContext.Session.GetString("email");
     _dbctx.Users.Where(x=>x.Email== 
 email).FirstOrDefault().Bio = bio;
     return Ok("Bio updated successfully") ;
   } 
}
```

Both forms are inside a page called Dashboard which has a model where I have defined the input field for the bio text area as a string property.
Is there a way to check which form submitted the request so each submission gets directed to the right controller. The first form contains no input fields except the submit button while the second form contains a text area input field and a submit button.

```
public class DashboardModel:PageModel{
  public IActionResult OnPost() {
  //works well for the first form and logs me out 
  RedirectToAction("LogOut", "Session") ;
  } 
  //the second form has a text field that needs validation and a submit button 
  [Required(ErrorMessage="bio field cannot be empty"] 
  [MaxLength(255)]
  [MinLength(30,ErrorMessage ="bio should be at least 30 characters long")]
  public string Bio{get;set} 
}
```

Second form looks like below

```
<form method="post">
<textarea asp-for="Bio" class="Form-control" name="Bio*></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Add Bio" class ="btn btn-primary" />
</form>
```

Comment: *"is it a must for a button to be nested inside a form"* what research have you done for that question?

Comment: @ThomasWeller, updated the post to remove that section of the post as I do research for it. :))

Comment: The form is handed to the right controller but now the problem is making sure the bio field is not empty

Answer (score 0):

We want to use [named handler methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#multiple-handlers-per-page). Now we can have a page with multiple forms in it.

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public string Message { get; private set; }

    [BindProperty]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "bio field cannot be empty")]
    [MaxLength(255)]
    [MinLength(5, ErrorMessage = "bio should be at least 30 characters long")]
    public string Bio { get; set; }

    public void OnPostLogout()
    {
        Message = "You Logged out";
    }

    public void OnPostRegister()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Message = "Error";
        }
        else
        {
            Message = "You Registered";
        }
    }
}
```

Named handler methods follow the same naming convention as standard handler methods `On<HTTP Method><Name of handler method>`

```
<form method="post" asp-page-handler="Logout">
    <p>Logout</p>
    <input type="submit" value="Logout" />
</form>
<form method="post" asp-page-handler="Register">
    <p>Register</p>
    <textarea asp-for="Bio" class="Form-control"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Register" />
</form>
<p>@Model.Message</p>
```

The name of the handler method is assigned to the `asp-page-handler` attribute of the form tag.

To make sure the field is not empty, the `Bio` property will be decorated with the [`BindProperty`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55648670/13454322) attribute. Without this attribute, the property will not take part in [model binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

`ModelState` has a property called `IsValid` that returns false if there are any errors.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I kind of already solved the problem but am leaving an upvote.

Comment: The solution is to directly submit the bio to controller and validate the input from there, set any errors in the session and redirect to the page where the error originated